# local_env.yml not loading before initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I have the following code in my config/application.rb to load some custom local environment variables

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

    require 'rails/all'

    # Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
    # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
    Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

    module App

        ...

    config.before_configuration do
      env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
      YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
        ENV[key.to_s] = value
      end if File.exists?(env_file)
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to use this with the railsconfig gem, so I can have sensitive information in settings.yml through referencing the ENV hash.
My settings.yml look like this:

```
default_request_ttl: 5
default_request_shared_key_size: 32
default_request_tunnel_provider: "SoftEther"
providers:
  soft_ether:
    server: <%= ENV["RSRS.PROVIDERS.SOFT_ETHER.SERVER"] %>
    port: "443"
    admin_hub_password: <%= ENV["RSRS.PROVIDERS.SOFT_ETHER.PASSWORD"] %>
    vpncmd_path: "/usr/local/bin/vpncmd"
```

The problem is that it seems that settings.yml is parsed before the environment variables are set. This way if I run rails console and call the Settings hash, this is what I get:

```
jruby-9.0.5.0 :007 > Settings
 => #<Config::Options default_request_ttl=5, default_request_shared_key_size=32, default_request_tunnel_provider="SoftEther", providers=#<Config::Options soft_ether=#<Config::Options server=nil, port="443", vpncmd_path="/usr/local/bin/vpncmd">>>
```

But after a Settings.reload! the variables are properly set:

```
jruby-9.0.5.0 :002 > Settings.reload!
 => #<Config::Options default_request_ttl=5, default_request_shared_key_size=32, default_request_tunnel_provider="SoftEther", providers=#<Config::Options soft_ether=#<Config::Options server="*.*.*.*", port="443", admin_hub_password="***************", vpncmd_path="/usr/local/bin/vpncmd">>>
```

I already tried putting the local_env load code in the config/environment.rb but the result is the same. Does anyone have a clue of what is happenning?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're not parsing the ERB that exists in your YML file.  For all of our initializers we're first opening the file, then we're parsing the ERB in the YML file but doing an `ERB.new` and then parsing that result through YML.

Here's a simple example of how we do it in our application: http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/using-rails-4-dot-1-secrets-for-configuration/

In general though, you'll want to first load up the configuration file like you're doing, then parse it through each parser, in turn.

Try something like the following:

```
config.before_configuration do
  require 'erb'
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(ERB.new(File.open(env_file))).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

Comment: Sorry but I think is misunderstood me. The file that is not parsed when it should is local_env.yml wich has no ruby code. Settings.yml is a file loaded by railsconfig, and it does erb parsing before loading the yaml file. The problem is that although I am reading and loading ENV variables from local_env at "before_config" they seem to not be available when railsconfig try to reads them.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" my problem using the [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem instead of trying to use a local_env file although I did not figured out why my previous solution was not working.